# How do I pass a variable into a sha1 method?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, pycharm, hashlib

I'm trying to get a hash out of inputs passed as arguments when launching the program. Looking into the documentation, I found the hexdigest method, and tried to implement it in a simple snippet:

```
import hashlib
import sys

passwords = sys.argv[1:]

for i in passwords:
    hashed_pwd = hashlib.sha1(b'{i}').hexdigest()
    print(hashed_pwd)
```

Problem is, whatever the arguments passed or their number, they always return the same hash: 54a97c18fc32f433bcc7e85fddb0ab6d7ee799ef.

Further examination reveals that {i} is not interpreted as a variable but as an actual string, which probably seems logical for Python developers but not to me since I'm a beginner. Is there a way to pass the variable into the sha1 method? It's not clear from the documentation.

Comment: It looks like you are expecting an f string without the `f` prefix. What you are looking for is probably something like `bytes(f'{i}', 'utf-8')` or even simpler `bytes(i, 'utf-8')` as to my knowledge, you cannot combine the `f` and `b` prefix.

Comment: Indeed! After much tinkering, I also found that `hashlib.sha1(str.encode(i)).hexdigest()` also works. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Another option is `i.encode('utf-8')`.